# how to write a mongodb query in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

The following query works in mongodb shell:

```
db.user.count( {$and: [ {"agent_id":{$exists:true}}, {"is_agent":{$ne:true}} ] } )
```

When I try it in python I get a different answer.  Here's the python code:

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

def getCollection(cient,dbname,collection):
    """Return a colleciton based on client, db and collection"""
    data_base = getattr(client, dbname)
    collObject = getattr(data_base, collection)
    return collObject   

userColl = getCollection(client, "hkpr_restore","user")

usersWithAgents = userColl.count( {"$and": [ {"agent_id":{"$exists":"true"}}, {"is_agent":{"$ne":"true"}} ] } )

print usersWithAgents
```

The results are about 11,000 for the mongo shell query and about 17,000 for the python script query.

Comment: Could you be more specific regarding how you get different answers?

Comment: about 11,000 for one the mongo shell query and about 17,000 for the python script query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:

```
"$exists": True
```

and not

```
"$exists": "true"
```

The same for `$ne`.